# Neural network example not working with sigmoid activation function

Tags: python, neural-network, numpy, activation-function

I'm running [the Neural Network example written in in BogoToBogo](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_Neural_Networks_Backpropagation_for_XOR_using_one_hidden_layer.php)

The program worked fine:

```
(array([0, 0]), array([  2.55772644e-08]))
(array([0, 1]), array([ 0.99649732]))
(array([1, 0]), array([ 0.99677086]))
(array([1, 1]), array([-0.00028738]))
```

The neural network learned XOR, using tanh as activation function by default. However, after I changed the activation function to "sigmoid"

```
nn = NeuralNetwork([2,2,1], 'sigmoid')
```

Now the program outputs:

```
epochs: 0
...
epochs: 90000
(array([0, 0]), array([ 0.45784467]))
(array([0, 1]), array([ 0.48245772]))
(array([1, 0]), array([ 0.47365194]))
(array([1, 1]), array([ 0.48966856]))
```

The output for the 4 inputs are all near 0.5. The result shows that neural network (with the sigmoid function) didn't learn XOR.

I was expecting the program would output:

- ~0 for (0, 0) and (1, 1)
- ~1 for (0, 1) and (1, 0)

Can somebody explain why this example with sigmoid doesn't work with XOR?

Comment: What did it work with?

Comment: Without any modification, it output

(array([0, 0]), array([  2.55772644e-08]))
(array([0, 1]), array([ 0.99649732]))
(array([1, 0]), array([ 0.99677086]))
(array([1, 1]), array([-0.00028738])).  I updated the question to include what worked fine.

Comment: What is the architecture of your net? 221?

Comment: Could you try running the program multiple times (remove any fixed RNG seed if it has one). Does it always get stuck, or maybe just some of the time? I am asking because with the simplest implementations, it is actually fairly common for this problem to get stuck, and not necessarily a fault in your code.

Comment: It always gets stuck if its sigmoid.

Comment: The architecture of the network is 2-2-1

Comment: @NeilSlater but can OP achieve an accuracy more than 3/4?

Comment: Well apparently I gave the wrong answer here I found a link for your troubled https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/creating-neural-net-for-xor-function

Comment: @NeilSlater pardon me for being a skeptic but can you somehow tell me with what combination of weights can you actually achieve that? All I can see is 2 decision boundaries are required and sigmoid can only supply 1...What am I missing here?

Comment: @DuttA: The possibility of handling multiple decision boundaries has very little to do with choice of activation function. A large number of non-linear functions will do just fine for that, including sigmoid. This is related to the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem) and XOR is a commonly-used example to demonstrate it. All you need is at least one hidden layer with enough neurons in it. Possibly what you are missing mathematically is using *bias*?

Comment: @NeilSlater as far as I see this is a classification problem with 0 as the threshold for sigmoid..Now we need 3 regions or 2 decision boundaries to separate them..This is probably achieved by the hidden layer, but if we have a single node in the final layer how will it be able to differentiate between the 3 regions..To me it seems impossible

Comment: @DuttaA: It is definitely possible. If it helps, you can think of the hidden layer as *mapping* the 3-part space into a 2-part one that can be separated linearly (you can plot the outputs of the hidden layer, and visualise this - it actually moves the points of XOR around so inputs that classify as 1s and 0s can be separated by a single line in the plane). I suggest you read about the universal approximation theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by myself. The reason of the difference is that the definition of prime of tanh in BogoToBogo (`tanh_prime`) takes arguments that's already applied with activation function:

```
def tanh_prime(x):
    return 1.0 - x**2
```

while `sigmoid_prime` is not. It calls sigmoid in it:

```
def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return sigmoid(x)*(1.0-sigmoid(x))
```

So the definition of `sigmoid_prime` seems *more accurate* than `tanh_prime`. Then why not `sigmoid` is working? It's because their parameters are already applied with the activation function.

## Background

The derivatives of sigmoid ($\sigma$) and tanh share the same attribute in which these derivatives can be expressed in terms of sigmoid and tanh functions themselves.

$$
\frac{d\tanh (x)}{d(x)} = 1 - \tanh (x)^2
$$
$$
\frac{d\sigma (x)}{d(x)} = \sigma(x) (1 - \sigma(x))
$$

When performing backpropagation to adjust their weights, neural networks apply the derivative ($g^{'}$) to the values that's before applied with activation function. In BogoToBogo's explanation, that's variable $ z^{(2)} $ in

$$
\delta^{(2)} = (\Theta^{(2)})^T \delta^{(3)} \cdot g^{'}(z^{(2)}).
$$

In its source code, the variable `dot_value` holds such values. The Python implementation, however, calls the derivative with the vector stored in variable `a`. The vector is after applied with activation function. Why?

I interpret this as optimization to leverage the fact that derivatives of `sigmoid` and `tanh` use their parameters only to apply the original function. As the neural network already holds the value after activation function (as `a`), it can skip unnecessary calculation of calling `sigmoid` or `tanh` when calculating the derivatives. That's why the definition of `tanh_prime` in BogoToBogo does NOT call original `tanh` within it. However, the definition of `sigmoid_prime`, on the other hand, calls `sigmoid` function unexpectedly, resulting in miscalculation of derivative function.

## Solution

Once I define `sigmoid_prime` in such a way that it assumes the parameter is already applied with sigmoid, then it works fine.

```
def sigmoid_prime(x):
    return x*(1.0-x)
```

Then calling the implementation with

```
nn = NeuralNetwork([2,2,1], 'sigmoid', 500000)
```

successfully outputs:

```
(array([0, 0]), array([ 0.00597638]))
(array([0, 1]), array([ 0.99216467]))
(array([1, 0]), array([ 0.99332048]))
(array([1, 1]), array([ 0.00717885]))
```